# Storing the entire output of a while loop

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I'm having problems storing the ouput of a while loop in Python3. The code below just stores the last output: 5702887

```
x = 1
y = 2
answer = []

while x < 4000000:
    y = x + y
    x = y - x
    answer.append(x)
```

How do I get x to store:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
```

Comment: What you want is in the 'answer' list-- 'x' is an integer.

Comment: This code works. You have a problem somewhere else. Tip: `x, y = y, x + y`

Comment: Combining the correct information from @EdwardMoseley and @HunterMcMillen. The list of values is in `answer` but does not contain `1`. If you really want `1` in the list, the loop code needs to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

i get the intended result with

```
print answer
```

and the result 5702887 with

```
print x
```

how do you try to get the result?

edit: without modifying the loop, you could start with

```
answer = [1]
```

Comment: answer is missing `x=1`

Comment: Ok...I figured it out. Thanks everybody

Comment: @Andrew Lastrapes how did you figured it out? and don't forget to vote

Answer (score 1):

As it is written, you will never get 1 in that list. The reason being is that your first loop through effectively is 3-1 which equals 2. If you know for a fact 1 needs to be included, just add it to the list already when you create it.

```
answer = [1]
```

Then run your loop, and it will append the rest of the data starting from 2 onwards to the list. Without knowing why 1 is explicitly needed, I have no basis to adjust the algorithm to get the desired result.

If you are allowed to change the values of x and y, then make:

```
x = 1
y = 1
```

This will give you the desired result in your answer[] list without needing to specify 1 initially in the list when creating it

```
x = 1
y = 1
answer = []

while x < 4000000:
    y = x + y
    x = y - x
    answer.append(x)

print(answer)
```

Output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887]
```

Comment: And really to the guy above me that added my answer into his AFTER I posted my answer? Not even in like a couple mins either but at least a half hour difference. wow . . . .